# Cannot find file on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to access a data file to get questions and answers for my "Quiz" application. 
If I access the file from the one on my desktop, it works fine. If I drag and drop the file into my netbeans, I cannot seem to access it. 
The file is in the package "quiz" along with my other classes.
Here's the code that works but I want to use the netbeans file.

```
String fileName = "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/QUIZ.DAT";
 try {
        //Make fileReader object to read the file
        FileReader file = new FileReader(new File(fileName));
        BufferedReader fileStream = new BufferedReader(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

To try and access the file on netbeans I use this but it cannot find it.

```
String fileName = "quiz/Quiz.DAT";
```

Comment: where did you put the file in netbeans? In the package or it the project root?

Comment: In the package "quiz"

Comment: try `src/quiz/Quiz.DAT`

Comment: Nope still nothing. If I hover over the file, it says it's unrecognized. If that is a reason?

Comment: could you give me the full path to the fiel? Just to make sure it's in the package.

Comment: C:\Users\Michael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Quiz\src\quiz\QUIZ.DAT

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36091/discussion-between-q99-and-michael-haywood)

Comment: Got it working. The name when I click on properties had .txt not .DAT. Yet the path and name I read in the package was .DAT. Changed it to .DAT in the name and works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, where MyClass is the class name. I have assumed the quiz.dat file is in the same package of the class.

```
InputStream f = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("QUIZ.DAT");
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
StringBuffer sbfFileContents = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sbfFileContents.append(line);
}
System.out.println(sbfFileContents.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

JJPA provided proper code. But let me enhance it better.

```
Project
   com.io
      test.txt
   com.root
      AccessFile.java
```

This is my program structure. I want to access file from package `io` So here is the code.

```
package com.root;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class AccessFile {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            InputStream f = AccessFile.class.getResourceAsStream("../io/test.txt");
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
            StringBuffer sbfFileContents = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sbfFileContents.append(line);
            }
            bReader.close();
            f.close();
            System.out.println(sbfFileContents.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read a file in your JAVA project and netbeans is not able to find it, put the file in the root directory of your project and it should be able to find it.